# Font Awesome 4.0.3 -circle not working

Tags: web, fonts, font-awesome

I am trying to use Font Awesome 4.0.3 with the `-circle` and `-o tags` and my icons disappear each time.

I am using it like so: `<i class="fa fa-twitter-circle-o fa-2x"></i>`

I don't get a blank square or anything else of the sorts; just a blank.

This works: `<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>`

Shouldn't the first work according to their [new naming conventions](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/whats-new/)?

*** EDIT ***

To elaborate a bit, I know I can stack them like you could in 3x, so for the time being, I have the following (since the circle is so thick):

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

Maybe I am misinterpreting the docs on the FA site, but I read it as the other *should* work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to stack them:

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

See Stacked icons: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Comment: That's what I have done to keep it looking right on the site. I was more thinking though that the docs, in my link on the OP states that the other should work. Am I reading that wrong? Guess I should elaborate in the OP...

Comment: I can see why you might think that. Especially when they say "combine them up…." I could be wrong, but while they have implemented a new naming convention, I don't think it allows you to combine different icons just by naming them so. It seems they were just trying to be more consistent in there naming so it's easier to code. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

You're right to think that Based on the [Font Awesome naming conventions](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/whats-new/#new-naming), what you're trying to do ought to work:

Ironically, their impetus for changing the naming convention was:

> A desire for better icon naming **consistency** and **predictability**

However, they have not done a good job at documenting which symbol variants are available.

Notice `fa-check-circle` works, but `fa-twitter-circle` doesn't.

If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for "circle" right on their [CSS source](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css), you'll notice that only the following symbols have a circle version:

- Play*
- Plus*
- Minus
- Times*
- Check*
- Question
- Info
- Crosshairs
- Exclamation
- Arrow*
- Dot
- Chevron*

**(some variants included as well)*

If you put in anything else, it will just become a random jarble of characters as far as the CSS is concerned.  It does not meet anyone of their predefined classes, so it won't treat it as anything special; which is why you lose the icon when you try to add the circle.

The alternative already proposed is to use [`fa-stack`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked) to manually combine a circle and a circle and a bird.  Since the circle seems a little thick, instead of inverting the bird with `-o`, you can invert the circle with `.fa-inverse` like this:

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Here's a **[Demo of the stacked option and every available circle icon](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/qfMdP/)**.

Here's a screnshot of what the demo looks like:

[image: screenshot]